# Text decoration underline property is not working UC browser

Tags: android, css, mobile, uc-browser

In UC browser text decoration underline is not working

```
h3 {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

UC Browser is not a standard browser like Chrome, Opera, Firefox or Safari. It is difficult to say where is the problem. You should contact the makers of the browser.

For standard browsers, you can check the compatibility on this site: 
http://caniuse.com/